# kendo-ui grid serverfiltering column filtering dropdownlist

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get the kendoui grid to support filtering with a dropdownlist as the filter. I want users to be able to pick from a list of all available options, rather than requiring them to type in the filter manually.

I have a shared datasource like this:

```
var transport = {
    read: {
        url: "/api/account/changes",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json"
    }
};
```

This method returns an object that looks like this:

```
public class Response {
  public IEnumerable Data { get;set; }
  public int Count { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable Users { get; set; }
}
```

I then have two datasources tied to the one transport:

```
var masterDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: transport,
    schema: {
        data: "Data",
        total: "Count",
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { type: "number" },
                User: { type: "string" },
                // other columns
                Value: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize: 20,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true
});

var usersDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: transport,
    schema: {
        data: "Users"
    }
});
```

My grid is bound to the masterDataSource:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: masterDataSource,
    height: 800,
    navigatable: true,
    resizable: true,
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: {
        mode: "single",
        allowUnsort: false
    },
    filterable: {
        extra: false,
        operators: {
            string: {
                startswith: "Starts with",
                eq: "Is equal to",
                neq: "Is not equal to"
            },
            date: {
                greaterthan: "Greater than",
                lessthan: "Less than"
            }
        }
    },
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
        {
            field: "User",
            title: "User",
            width: 130,
            filterable: {
                ui: userFilter
            }
        },
        // other columns
        {
            field: "Value",
            title: "Value",
            filterable: false,
            width: 70
        }
    ]
});
```

Then I have defined a function to represent the filter:

```
function userFilter(element) {
    console.log("setting up user filter");
    element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: usersDataSource,
        optionLabel: "--Select One--"
    });
    console.log("set up user filter");
}
```

However, my userFilter function is never called and I get the generic column filtering, rather than a dropdownlist filter. This layout looks a lot like the filtering example at http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/filter-menu-customization.html, but I can't seem to get the dropdownlist to work like theirs.

I appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're never making a call to your userFilter function. Under your filterable property, you need to add a ui property and set it equal to the function you wish to call. Like this:

`filterable: {
        ui: userFilter
    }`

Hope that helps.